# Dynamically build list comprehension in Haskell

Tags: dynamic, haskell, list-comprehension

I am curious if it is possible to dynamically build a list comprehension in Haskell.

As an example, if I have the following:

```
all_pows (a,a') (b,b') = [ a^y * b^z | y <- take a' [0..], z <- take b' [0..] ]
```

I get what I am after

```
*Main> List.sort $ all_pows (2,3) (5,3)
[1,2,4,5,10,20,25,50,100]
```

However, what I'd really like is to have something like

```
all_pows [(Int,Int)] -> [Integer]
```

So that I can support `N` pairs of arguments without building `N` versions of `all_pows`. I'm still pretty new to Haskell so I may have overlooked something obvious. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The magic of the list monad:

```
ghci> let powers (a, b) = [a ^ n | n <- [0 .. b-1]]
ghci> powers (2, 3)
[1,2,4]
ghci> map powers [(2, 3), (5, 3)]
[[1,2,4],[1,5,25]]
ghci> sequence it
[[1,1],[1,5],[1,25],[2,1],[2,5],[2,25],[4,1],[4,5],[4,25]]
ghci> mapM powers [(2, 3), (5, 3)]
[[1,1],[1,5],[1,25],[2,1],[2,5],[2,25],[4,1],[4,5],[4,25]]
ghci> map product it
[1,5,25,2,10,50,4,20,100]
ghci> let allPowers list = map product $ mapM powers list
ghci> allPowers [(2, 3), (5, 3)]
[1,5,25,2,10,50,4,20,100]
```

This probably deserves a bit more explanation.

You could have written your own

```
cartesianProduct :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
cartesianProduct [] = [[]]
cartesianProduct (list:lists)
  = [ (x:xs) | x <- list, xs <- cartesianProduct lists ]
```

such that `cartesianProduct [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]` ⇒ `[[1,2,4],[1,2,5],[1,2,6],[1,3,4],[1,3,5],[1,3,6]]`.

However, [comprehensions](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#list-comprehensions) and [monads](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension#List_monad) are intentionally similar.  The standard Prelude has [`sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Asequence), and when `m` is the list monad `[]`, it actually does exactly what we wrote above.

As another shortcut, [`mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3AmapM) is simply a composition of `sequence` and `map`.

For each inner list of varying powers of each base, you want to multiply them to a single number.  You could write this recursively

```
product list = product' 1 list
  where product' accum [] = accum
        product' accum (x:xs)
          = let accum' = accum * x
             in accum' `seq` product' accum' xs
```

or using a fold

```
import Data.List
product list = foldl' (*) 1 list
```

but actually, [`product :: Num a => [a] -> a`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Aproduct) is already defined!  I love this language ☺☺☺

Comment: `let powers (a, b) = [a ^ n | n <- [0 .. b-1]]`

Comment: @Tordek Thanks, I skimmed over the original a bit too quickly.